# unattended-upgrade -- Working configuration for notification emails

Tags: apt, upgrade, email, notification

I'm trying to activate the notification emails from `unattended-upgrade` package. I put a mail address into my configuration, installed `mailx` and created a configuration for mailx in `/root/.mailrc`. I tested successfully `mailx` with the `.mailrc`.

Info: the mail inside the unattended-upgrade configuration differs from the mail inside `.mailrc`.

I run `unattended-upgrade -v -d --dry-run` but I don't get a mail. There is also no debug information about sending a mail.

So what am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any information or working configuration about such a setup.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:
Patches (security) are getting installed correctly. So, the tool is running. I just checked the log files on the server. But I still get no mail from the system. And yes: the mail address below is not my real mail address.

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// List of packages to not update (regexp are supported)
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
//      "vim";
//      "libc6";
//      "libc6-dev";
//      "libc6-i686";
};

// This option allows you to control if on a unclean dpkg exit
// unattended-upgrades will automatically run
//   dpkg --force-confold --configure -a
// The default is true, to ensure updates keep getting installed
//Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "false";

// Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
// they can be interrupted with SIGUSR1. This makes the upgrade
// a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
// is running is possible (with a small delay)
//Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

// Install all unattended-upgrades when the machine is shuting down
// instead of doing it in the background while the machine is running
// This will (obviously) make shutdown slower
//Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed. E.g. "user@example.com"
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "mymail@myprovider.com";

// Set this value to "true" to get emails only on errors. Default
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "false";

// Do automatic removal of new unused dependencies after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";

// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION*
//  if the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";

// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/mailx` is probably just a link to something like `/etc/alternatives/mailx`. In order to debug this you could try replacing `/usr/bin/mailx` with a small script that prints out debugging information to a log file, then calls `/etc/alternatives/mailx "$@"`.

Comment: As I said: `mailx`is working properly. `unattended-upgrade` is not sending mails. How does `unattended-upgrade` know how to use `mailx` and what configuration to use?

Comment: 1) I just want security updates. The config is right. I can see in the logs that these patches are getting installed. 2) Who will post a real mail address in an open community?

Comment: I just read your full post from my computer and saw the note in question it wasn't your real email. I must have missed that on my first read on my not-so-smart phone. Although Canonical and Stack Exchange organizations have our email addresses I agree not many people post their email addresses unless they are professionals who enjoy traffic. Mine does show up from time to time but I get very few emails (usually about bug reports) which is way better than the ad-mail I get from e-bay or other promotion orientated sites. I was thinking today of getting one of my apps to email me so I'll test.

Comment: `unattended-upgrade` is looking for `/usr/bin/mail`. This probably will be a simlink to `/etc/alternatives/mail` which could be a simlink to the mailx program.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades is referencing an address for a local mail server (hence the default is root and there's no @ in the default conifg) Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26666/can-i-change-roots-email-address-or-forward-it-to-an-external-address

Comment: The reports will not be mailed in `--dry-run` mode or when there are no changes.

Comment: I succeeded by using [ssmtp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=SSMTP) instead of `mailx`.

Comment: @Carl I do not have `/usr/bin/mail`, but I get mail from `unattended-upgrade`.

Comment: ssmtp *has been orphaned since 2019-03-19. msmtp can be used as an alternative.* according to https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP
Does msmtp work for this?  Do you need any other packages besides msmtp?
Is anyone working on supporting a more modern and secure notification method than email for the many notifications that an Ubuntu server may want to send?

Comment: Looks like msmtp should work, and does TLS encryption at least. See e.g. [Simple way to get email notifications from a linux server](https://mytechiethoughts.com/linux/simple-way-to-get-email-notifications-from-a-linux-server/)